# To bypass referral check

Tags: html-content-extraction, referrals

Is there any way to bypass the referral check applied by some site in order to avoid there data from being extracted. Like if you follow this [link](http://www.nse-india.com/marketinfo/equities/ajaxGetQuote.jsp?symbol=ABAN&series=EQ)!

You will get Access Denied Error. However , if you just go this [link](http://www.nse-india.com/)!, it takes you to home page and on filling on any quote say ABAN , it follows exactly the same GET request as the link used above.

Can anyone please suggest me some solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your referrer to the correct value. You can spoof the value to anything you want programatically or by visiting the correct url before visiting the target url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like `wget` which allows you to set your own referer value. This won't work on sites which expect more than that as their protection value (and anyone interested in protecting the delivery of their content might also look for a cookie or ip address as well).